Add to Cart function and customer login problem
I’m experiencing an issue with my Magento site 2.4.6 after modifying the .htaccess file for security headers. After making these changes, the “Add to Cart” function and customer login are not working properly. Specifically:
• When items are added to the cart, the shopping cart remains empty.
• After customers log in, they are immediately logged out automatically.
I’ve already tried disabling all the headers, but the issue persists. and I have no idea how can I solved this problem.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or could offer insights into what might be causing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here if my web site www.koya.com.au(https://www.koya.com.au)
Thank you!

Please explain which changes you made in the htaccess file.
Also please provide the code of the htaccess file
